# Iterating over a long iterator in an almost uniformly sampled random order without large memory requirements

Tags: python, iterator, permutation

I want to iterate over integers in the range `0` to `N-1`, where `N` is a large number.
This can easily be done with `for i in range(N):`.

However, I want to iterate the numbers in a random order.
This can also easily be done using something like:

```
from random import shuffle
a = list(range(N))
shuffle(a)
for i in a:
      do_something(i)
```

The problem with this approach is that it requires storing in memory the entire list of numbers.
(`shuffle(range(N))` raises an error). This make it not practical for my purposes for large `N`.

I would like to have an object which is an iterator (just like `range(N)`), which does not store all numbers in the memory (again, just like `range(N)`), and which iterates in a random order.

Now, when I say "random order" I really mean that the order is sampled from the uniform distribution over the set of all permutations of `(0,1,...,N-1)`. I know that this number is potentially very large (`N!`), and therefore if the iterator would need to represent which permutation it uses it would need to be very large in memory.

Therefore, I can settle on "random order" having the meaning of "looks like a uniform distribution although it is actually not", in some sense which I have not defined.

If I had such an iterator, this is how I would operate it:

```
a = random_order_range(N) # this object takes memory much smaller than then factorial of N
for i in a:
    do_something(i)
```

Any ideas how this can be done?

---

**EDIT1:**

Actually, what I am really interested in is that the memory consumption will be even less than `~N`, if possible... Maybe something like `O(k*N)` for some `k` that could be much smaller than 1.

Comment: I assume you don't want to get duplicate integers? Also, do you plan to consume *all* integers, or only some of them? Depending on the answer, the solution could be very easy or quite hard ;)

Comment: The linked dupe even has a python answer.

Comment: @Guybrush right, I don't want duplicate integers. And I do want to consume all integers.

Comment: @AndrasDeak right. It indeed seems like the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import functools, random, itertools  
from collections import deque
import random
from bloom_filter import BloomFilter

def random_no_repeat(random_func, limit):
    already_returned = BloomFilter()
    count = 0
    while True:
        i = random_func()
        if i not in already_returned:
            count += 1
            already_returned.add(i)
            yield i
            if (count == limit):
                break

def count_iter_items(iterable):
    counter = itertools.count()
    deque(itertools.zip_longest(iterable, counter), maxlen=0)  # (consume at C speed)
    return next(counter)

N = 1e5
random.seed(0)
random_gen = random_no_repeat(functools.partial(random.randint, 0, int(N)))

for index, i in  enumerate(random_gen):
    print(index, i)
```

Comment: Good answer. But there is no guarantee here that all integers in the range are generated. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure about the space and timing requirements, but this should be far less then `N!` - by fixing the limits `low` and `high` and the `set` of `seen` inner ones it should also not need overly long towards the end to draw a number then when you simply bruteforce from N and check if in `seen`:

```
import random 

def random_range(N): 
    seen = set()
    low = 0
    high = N
    seen = set()
    while low < high:
        k = random.choice(range(low,high))
        if k in seen:
            # already drafted - try again
            continue
        else:
            yield k

            seen.add(k)

            # fix lower
            while low in seen:
                seen.remove(low)
                low += 1

            # fix upper
            while high-1 in seen:
                seen.remove(high-1)
                high -= 1

for i in random_range(20):
    print(i, end = ", ")
```

Output:

```
7, 2, 5, 18, 11, 3, 6, 10, 14, 9, 15, 17, 19, 0, 16, 4, 1, 12, 13, 8,
```

If you plug in `N` as 2^63 the `seen` set will grow huge before it shrinks down because the probability of hitting the low or high spot is small - thats what makes about the most memory consumption.

The runtime gets worse the fuller `seen` is in respect to `range(low,high)` because it might need 2000 continues to hit a random number thats not in `seen` already:

```
# pseudo 
seen = { 1-99999,100001-99999999999 } 
low = 0
high = 99999999999+2
```

This would not be "reduceable" and there are only 3 numbers left to draw from `range(0, 99999999999+2)` - but the chance to get to such a thing is also kinda tiny.

Your choice ;o)

Comment: right, this approach takes O(N) memory (at least in the worst case) which is indeed much less than O(N!). However, there is a chance here of generating the same integer twice. Also, following this answer I edited the question since I realize now that I would actually like something smaller than O(N)...

Comment: I mean, smaller than ~N

Comment: @Lior - where do you see the chance of an integer to be reported more then once?

Comment: you are right, my mistake. There is no chance for an integer being yielded twice.